# ios - get today 10 AM

Tags: iphone, ios, nsdate

How to get Today 10 AM and Tomorrow 10 AM in ios?

```
NSDateComponents *nowComponents = [calendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit | NSWeekCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit fromDate:today];
```

[nowComponents setHour:10];

This is not giving proper response. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code, hope it'll work. If you want to get tomorrow's `10 am` then, set hour to `34`.

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
NSTimeZone *gmt = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"];
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier: NSGregorianCalendar];
[gregorian setTimeZone:gmt];
NSDateComponents *components = [gregorian components: NSUIntegerMax fromDate: date];
[components setHour: 10];
[components setMinute:0];
[components setSecond: 0];
NSDate *newDate = [gregorian dateFromComponents: components];
NSLog(@"Date%@", newDate);
[gregorian release];
```